Can not run a .exe file which compiled with Graphviz libraries on Windows
DESCRIPTION:
I want to involve a Graphviz library gvc in my Cpp project.
The Cpp project is an extremely simplified syntax analyser, and I include the graphviz/gvc.h to draw syntax analysis tree.
I built and run the project successfully before involving the graphviz, and the program returned an expected result. But I encountered difficulties when I tried involve graphviz in.
I construct the project via CMake and MinGW tools.
Then I wrote my CMakeLists.txt as below:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(Analyser)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
set(GV_HOME "D:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz")
file(GLOB SRC CONFIGURE_DEPENDS src/*.cpp)

include_directories(${GV_HOME}/include)
include_directories(include)

link_directories(${GV_HOME}/lib)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main/main.cpp ${SRC})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} gvc cgraph)


ENVIRONMENT:
compiler toolchain: MinGW-64 with GCC 13.2.0
CMake version: 3.27.9
graphviz: obtained from official website and was built on Visual Studio C++ 2019
System: Windows 10 with 64bit x86 CPU
PROBLEM:
Then I successfully compiled the project and got an .exe file.
Well, the strange thing occured: It run without returning any results on the terminal.
I can't figure out the reason...
And the project structure is like:
project---
         |*--src
         |      |\*--main
         |      |        |--main.cpp
         |      |        |--input.cpp
         |      |
         |      |--LexicalAnalyser.cpp
         |      |--SyntaxAnalyser.cpp
         |      |--ErrorProcessor.cpp
         |      |--utils.cpp
         |
         |*--build
         |
         |*--include
         |          |--SyntaxAnalyser.h
         |          |--LexicalAnalyser.h
         |          |--utils.h
         |
         |--CMakeLists.txt


At first, I couldn't compile the project when involved the graphviz.
Then I try to add an entry cgraph in the target_link_libraries() in CMakeLists.txt and successfully compile it in the end, while can't run the .exe normally.
I wanna konw how to address that question.
EFFORTS:

try to debug: use gdb to debug, but can not run gdb successfully and it exited with information:[Thread 8244.0x1d30 exited with code 3221225781], During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135.

try to debug on a basic .exe which includes graphviz/gvc to draw a simple directed graph. And still, successfully complied it yet failed to run it with expected result returned. Also tried to debug on it and encountered the same information as mentioned above.


SOLUTION(2024/5/1):

It was caused by NOT placing the necessary DLL in the working directory although I had set a path to graphviz's binary directory in system environment.

So, to address it, things need to do is that explicitly point out the path to DLL directory in CMakeLists.txt or make a duplication of DLLs in an appropriate directory under the project.



Run your program in a debugger and see where it exits or crashes?

Normally when a program runs and then exits without any results on the terminal, it means that everything is fine. Unless you print something to std::cout.

Oh, I forgot to note that I use a std::cin to get the input from terminal.  Thus it shouldn't end before I input nothing.

I use an cmake extension in vscode to debug, and the starnge thing is: the debugger  ends without output anything even though I set a breakpoint at the begining of the main function

Can you create an [mcve] and debug/run that?  The next step would be to backup the code, then add a little bit of code and debug it.  Repeat until the program doesn't run.  The last change shows you where the program stops running.

I tried to create a minimal example which only involves the basic graphviz function, It was designed to output a simple directed graph. But It can't still return a result, I tried to debug on it. Then gdb throws an information that ERROR: Unable to start debugging. GDB exited unexpectedly. ERROR: During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135. . So now I guess the problem is caused by incorrectly including the graphviz libraries.

0xc0000135 is an error code indicating a DLL could not be found. Do you have the DLL in your working directory?

That means it could not find one ore more dynamic link libraries (DLL) that the program is trying to load at startup.

Yes, the problem is caused by dll. I initially handle it by copying the WHOLE dll libraries of graphviz to the working directory, the next step is to figure out which part is necessary to be remained, but the problem is acually addressed. thx bro!

The problem is caused by lacking necessary DLLs. So the program couldn't run without loading the DLL, it naturally ends up like nothing happens at all.
Inluding the third-party libraries(graphviz) here needs to take the DLL into consideration.
